# OnItemClickListener is not executed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

in the mainActivity i have a `listView` with a cutomised adapter, the adapter class extends `BaseAdapter`.

in the mainActivity i am trying to show a message when an item is clikced, so i called `OnItemClickListener` and inside it i show a `toast`. but when i click an item the nothing is displayed.

please et me know what i am missing.

**MainActivity**:

```
private void setUpListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.topicsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.topics.length; i++) {
        this.topicsList.add(topics[i]);
    }

    this.adapter = new listViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.topicsList);
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(listViewitemListener);
}
....
....
private OnItemClickListener listViewitemListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

**BaseAdapter**:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

    tv.setText(this.arrayList.get(position));

    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root of your `list_items_layout`.